# Is there a way to create dynamic views that reflect on the Entities rather than using lots of scaffolded views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, C#, Razor,  Entity Framework 5

I have quite a number of entities that I need to build "Grid" Views for. Currently I use the VS scaffolder to create the seperate Views. However I am ending up with lots of Views that all do a similar job but on different data entities. It might be a better idea to create one View that is more generic that can react to the different entity definitions and thus create the appropriate view at runtime.

Any thoughts appreciated?

Thanks.

P.S Perhaps there is a utility or library in Nuget that can help with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a generic view model and bind it to a shared view, instead of binding different views to the EF entites directly. The various EF entities can be translated to this common view model. That way you only need a single view for all your grids

Comment: Thks for this. Intriguing idea. I use annotations quite a bit, and I could see the mapping of the display and validation annotations may be an issue, or am I missing something. By translation you are talking about using something like "Automapper"?